# CSS not reflecting in the HTML file in Glassfish 4

Tags: java, html, css, glassfish

I am trying to run an external HTML file on the server. And the CSS is not getting reflected though the path given is right. I tried placing the CSS folder insisde WebComponents and also in Web-Inf, it didn’t work both times.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="home/hduser/workspace/trial/WebContent/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="home/hduser/workspace/trial/WebContent/css/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  …
</html>
```

And also repeatedly refreshing the page or clean and refreshing the project not helping isn’t reflecting the changes to the HTML.

Comment: Did you try `Ctrl` + `F5` to refresh the page without cache?

Comment: Open the developer console and see if the file is loaded if you not sure open the file location in the browser and see if you can access to it my guess is wrong file permissions

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem, and this works for me:

1. Save all the changes of your files.
2. Publish that changes on server. I'm already using Eclipse Neon.1, and you can use the "Publish" option selecting the server and then using `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`P`.

[Capture of Publish option in Eclipse Neon.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N15dr.png)

3. Run your project on the server and then use `Ctrl`+`F5` in your web browser.

I hope this will help you and others who have the same issue, seeing that the question is from one year ago.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the absolute path with the `${baseRef}` for Root path.

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="${baseRef}/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="${baseRef}/css/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: (Hint: write `<!-- language: lang-html -->` before your code block to [highlight](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) it as HTML)

Comment: I tried doing this, but yeah where should the css files be places if i do this?

Comment: `WebContent` -> `CSS` -> `bootstrap.min.css`